# Humorous story in which future archaeologists find a motel room and they believe to have found a great tomb similar to that of Tutankhamun

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, humor

I read it in Reader's Digest in the seventies. Archaeologists interpreted everyday objects as the TV set and the toilet seat to be sacred and precious.

Comment: The Toot-n-come-inn motel IIRC

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is [Motel of the Mysteries](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/108831.Motel_of_the_Mysteries) by David Macaulay

The blurb reads as follows;

> **It is the year 4022; all of the ancient country of Usa has been buried
>   under many feet of detritus from a catastrophe that occurred back in
>   1985. Imagine, then, the excitement that Howard Carson, an amateur archeologist at best, experienced when in crossing the perimeter of an
>   abandoned excavation site he felt the ground give way beneath him and
>   found himself at the bottom of a shaft, which, judging from the DO NOT
>   DISTURB sign hanging from an archaic doorknob, was clearly the
>   entrance to a still-sealed burial chamber.**
>
> **Carson's incredible
>   discoveries, including the remains of two bodies, one of then on a
>   ceremonial bed facing an altar that appeared to be a means of
>   communicating with the Gods and the other lying in a porcelain
>   sarcophagus in the Inner Chamber, permitted him to piece together the
>   whole fabric of that extraordinary civilization**

one of the reviews specifically mentions that one segment concerns the idea that

> **"that the toilet seat is a sacred collar one must wear before
>   shouting, down the hole, to the gods below"**

[image]

Comment: One of my favorite books ever!