# Future Archeology in New York City

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I vividly remember what I think was a short story about archaeologists in the future digging through the ruins of Grand Central Station. They describe what I, the reader who is from New York, know to be a PAY TOILET. I found their speculation about the pay toilet and its contents to be hysterically funny.

55 years later, I would love to find and re-read it AND share it with my daughter and wife, at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162247/51379

Comment: @Adamant I suggest you make it an answer, so that we can close it as a dupe.

Comment: @Edlothiad - All we need is a confirmatory comment from the poster. I prefer not to post duplicate answers when possible.

Comment: @Adamant This is true, but usually people prefer an answer, and is the usual course of action. If you're worried about being a thief say I held you at knifepoint.

Comment: @Edlothiad - The usual course of action with duplicate questions is not to post an answer if one knows or suspects them to be duplicate. It’s a bit trickier with story ID, but I try to apply the same policy.

Comment: @Adamant they're two different policies. Rand can confirm the validity of the following, but for story-ID there normally needs to be two answers both with confirmation before it can be closed. Answers are often given in cases like this for a tick to be given or a comment to be left.

Comment: @Adamant I've solved the issue.

Comment: @Edlothiad - No, there needs to be *confirmation* by both posters. That could be in the form of an (accepted) answer, or it could be in the form of a comment. There was a meta question establishing this. I think avoiding tediously duplicated content (as with the dozen or so questions about “All Summer in a Day”) is a pretty good reason to opt for comments over answers.... Indeed, Valorum’s answer, below (while good in itself) is nearly a direct copy of…Valorum’s answer on the duplicate question!

Comment: That is most definitely NOT the story, although in the story I read, the porcelain fixture is theorized as a religious shrine of some sort.  The coin receptacle, to enter the pay toilet, was postulated to be a receptacle for donations.

Comment: Does the story include an archaeologist building a theory about paying, and then suggesting an economic model of capitalism,. only to be laughed at by all the other scientists? I have a vague memory of such a story.

Comment: Probably not the answer but a good story: Digging the Weans: https://harpers.org/archive/1956/11/digging-the-weans/

Comment: NOT an economic motive.  DEFINITELY speculation about RELIGION.  The ENTIRE pay toilet is theorized as a religious shrine with all parts given various religious functions.  COIN BOX obvious donation!

Answer (score 20):

Could it be [Report on "Grand Central Terminal"](https://library.ucsd.edu/dc/object/bb26295467) by Leo Szilard?  The article appeared in *The University of Chicago Magazine* in 1952.  It describes pay toilets at Grand Central Station:

> Another point, however, was much harder to understand. This problem arose because we found that the door of each and every cubicle in the depository was locked by a rather complicated gadget. Upon investigation of these gadgets it was found that they contained a number of round metal disks. By now we know that these ingenious gadgets barred entrance to the cubicle until an additional disk was introduced into them through a slot; at that very moment the door became unlocked, permitting access to the cubicle.

It goes on to speculate about the significance of the "disks" and the reasons for locking the doors.

Comment: I can't speak for the original poster, but this looks like a winner to me: it's got pay toilets, and it's the right age. Us sci-fi readers will most likely have read it in Groff Conklin's anthology [*Great Science Fiction by Scientists*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15925), which was first published just 55 years ago.

Comment: This COULD be it.  I'll have to find and read it and let you folks know.  THANKS!

Comment: Thanks to user 90039, I downloaded the pdf and glanced through it to the "important" part.  WONDERFUL story but NOT the right one!

Answer (score 13):

Could this be [Motel of the Mysteries](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/108831.Motel_of_the_Mysteries) (1979) by David Macaulay?

The blurb reads as follows;

> **It is the year 4022; all of the ancient country of Usa has been buried
>   under many feet of detritus from a catastrophe that occurred back in
>   1985. Imagine, then, the excitement that Howard Carson, an amateur archeologist at best, experienced when in crossing the perimeter of an
>   abandoned excavation site he felt the ground give way beneath him and
>   found himself at the bottom of a shaft, which, judging from the DO NOT
>   DISTURB sign hanging from an archaic doorknob, was clearly the
>   entrance to a still-sealed burial chamber.**
>
> **Carson's incredible
>   discoveries, including the remains of two bodies, one of then on a
>   ceremonial bed facing an altar that appeared to be a means of
>   communicating with the Gods and the other lying in a porcelain
>   sarcophagus in the Inner Chamber, permitted him to piece together the
>   whole fabric of that extraordinary civilization**

one of the reviews specifically mentions that one segment concerns the idea that

> **"that the toilet seat is a sacred collar one must wear before
>   shouting, down the hole, to the gods below"**

[image]

Comment: Could be. Or maybe some other story in the [Addled Archaeology](http://www.locusmag.com/Perspectives/2009/08/gary-westfahl-addled-archaeology-of.html) microgenre. Possible problems with MotM: (1) Published only 38 years ago, OP says 55 years. (2) OP emphasized PAY TOILET. Is there really a PAY toilet in MotM? Pay toilets were in places like train stations and airports. What would a pay toilet be doing in a motel?

Comment: @User14111 - We shall have to wait and see whether OP confirms or denies. Given the length of time since reading,  it's reasonable to assume that many of the fine details are incorrect.

Comment: @user14111 - I'm pretty happy with the answer as it stands. If you think there's another story in the same genre that fits the profile better it might be worth raising it as a new answer

Comment: Do you really need to post nearly the *exact* same answer to both questions? What can the OP gain from this answer that they can’t get just from following a link to the other question?

Comment: That is most definitely NOT the story, although in the story I read, the porcelain fixture is theorized as a religious shrine of some sort. The coin receptacle, to enter the pay toilet, was postulated to be a receptacle for donations

Answer (score 0):

it could be the short story "History Lesson" from Arthur C.  Clarke, from the book Expedition to Earth, which is a collection of short stories from the Author. In the story in question there is a misinterpretation of the working of public toilets as places of worship Where one would put a token (coin) to the gods to enter the sanctuary (bathroom), also a funny confusion about signs that allowed non-smokers to be there, but not smokers, the aliens (if i remember correctly, from venus in the future), related that to pictures they found of paler people (non-smokers) and darker-skinned people as a more smokey look, so, smokers. The same event that ended life on earth make for the conditions for life to develop on venus. The most interesting thing the aliens found was a movie film that they managed to get to work, and try to interpret.

Comment: You've managed to mix and mangle at least two stories.  The thing about the people from venus finding and playing what turns out to be a Disney movie does **not** involve the Venusians engaging in wild speculation about bathrooms and gods.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, have been thinking about it also. you are correct. But i'm now sure that i'm mixing exactly the story that the OP has in mind and history lesson. The bits the smokers/non-smokers, other bits about winged men ( as they thought that the amount of angels in paintings was a representation of a minority of humans), and the worship booth/toilet are from the same story as the OP. Now burning neurons trying to remember where i read that, now that i have the plot clear.

Comment: Sounds like you've identified EXACTLY the right story.  I need to go find and read it to know for sure.  I read a lot of Arthur C. Clarke, Heinlein and Asimov in my youth, so this author is very likely.  THANK YOU SO MUCH.  I will comment after I've found and read the story.