# SF Book Toilet as Mediatative/Religious Device. Possibly by C. J. Cherryh, But Maybe Not

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book back in the 80s. I only remember a few things about the book.
Set in the future, probably a hundred years or more. There are several humanoid lifeforms in the society. The heroine/hero is the result of 2 or more of them interbreeding. One of the lifeforms is somewhat feline. The heroine/hero is born a normal human which I think was rare for the time.
Some members of the society use old style human toilets as religious/meditative objects because they don't know what they are. This is a minor plot point in the story and is only mentioned once or twice. One character has a mental snicker about this because he/she does know what they're for. It begins and, I think, is mostly set on a space station or large spaceship. There's some sort of intrigue going on.
The cover was mostly reddish. Similar to [this edition](https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388644716l/317621.jpg) of "The Witches of Karres"

If you took that cover, split it down the middle, threw away the left half and stretched out the right half, it looked sorta like that.
I've looked at Cherryh's books list, but nothing rings a bell, so it may not be one of hers.

I've posted this query in a few other places on the 'net. 2 other people recognized the toilet thing, but can't remember what it was in.

Books suggested and eliminated are as follows.

<s>Cyteen,
Cuckoo's Egg,
Hestia,
Chanur series, all by Cherryh.</s>

Sholan Alliance series

Kzinti series by Niven

Hainish series by Le Guin

Breed to Come by Andre Norton

The Legacy of Luhr by Kurtz

Cat Karina by Coney

Nostrilia by Cordwainer Smith

The Spell Sword by Bradley

Psion by Joan Vinge

The Wanderer by Fritz Leiber

Books of Jo Clayton

Xenogenesis by Butler

The Cool War by Pohl

And everything on this list of books with feline characters.
http://anthrozine.com/site/lbry/cat.novels.html

I want to emphasize that the MC is not feline, just one of her/his parents or grandparents is. The MC is a normal human.

Comment: I don't know about the feline aspect and the time is a bit further in the future. But, the following link has some short stories about toilets as religious objects. Maybe these were in the same collection with another story about felines?   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169822/future-archeology-in-new-york-city   With the name of the short stories you might try the following to find the collections for them:   http://www.philsp.com/homeville/isfac/0start.htm   and   http://www.isfdb.org/

Comment: I recall in Lord of Light by Roger Zelazny they were suppressing toilets to keep the people in order, not sure if the use of them was subverted to keep people distracted. I think people also took animal bodies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_Light

Comment: No, it was one complete novel. There might have been an excerpt published as a short story, but the book wasn't a short story collection. It isn't Lord of Light. The toilets weren't suppressed, just no longer in common use. Thanks for trying, Beichst and Blair.

Comment: A bump back up, if that's allowed. If not, please delete.