# Looking for children's book, future archaeologists uncover modern-day items

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

About twenty years ago (so, late 90s, but the book could've been older) I remember my mother read me a book. The basic premise was that for some reason, modern society had collapsed, been destroyed, or otherwise been forgotten, and a new human civilization had developed. Humans from this far future then rediscovered various items from modern times and tried to interpret what they were used for; this book described their findings.

I remember this being a picture book, but not being very colorful. Possibly it was going for a sort of Victorian/Planet-of-the-Apes aesthetic. I recall the future society being less advanced than our own, and they ascribed religious significance to a lot of the things they found (and were generally wrong about everything). I think the idea of the book was to be satirical and/or humorous, but also as a young child I was freaked out by the idea of everyone dying in some cataclysm.

I'd like to find this book again because I think I'd more appreciate the humor and I want to see if it's still as unsettling as I remember, but I have no idea how to even begin to look for it.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169822/future-archeology-in-new-york-city

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162247/humorous-story-in-which-future-archaeologists-find-a-motel-room-and-they-believe

Comment: One of those, presumably.

Comment: @Valorum yep, probably. At least one of them looks promising