# Early 90's Book Fair book about a post-apocalyptic society where people find skeletons "worshipping" a box - it was illustrated

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for the title of a book that was likely purchased at a 1990 book fair. It had a blue cover and was likely about people sifting through the rubble, houses, etc. after what seems to be an attack or something related to the end of humanity.  The book had a picture of people finding skeletons that they thought were worshipping a box but it had really been people watching TV when whatever happened, happened.

Comment: Something something Addled Archaeology

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 14):

*[Motel of the Mysteries](https://www.goodreads.com/ar/book/show/108831.Motel_of_the_Mysteries)* by David Macaulay

[image: Blue front cover of Motel of the Mysteries]

> It is the year 4022; all of the ancient country of Usa has been buried under many feet of detritus from a catastrophe that occurred back in 1985. Imagine, then, the excitement that Howard Carson, an amateur archeologist at best, experienced when in crossing the perimeter of an abandoned excavation site he felt the ground give way beneath him and found himself at the bottom of a shaft, which, judging from the DO NOT DISTURB sign hanging from an archaic doorknob, was clearly the entrance to a still-sealed burial chamber. Carson's incredible discoveries, including the remains of two bodies, one of then on a ceremonial bed facing an altar that appeared to be a means of communicating with the Gods and the other lying in a porcelain sarcophagus in the Inner Chamber, permitted him to piece together the whole fabric of that extraordinary civilization.

[image: Worshipping the box]

[image: Alternative image worshiping the box, with tagged artifacts]

Comment: It would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162247/humorous-story-in-which-future-archaeologists-find-a-motel-room-and-they-believe/162259#162259

Comment: Thank you! This is it!

Comment: @Kayray40 Excellent! If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer via the checkmark, that would make it clear the question has been answered.